# Ultra high refresh rate monitor

Tags: display, refresh-rate

I was searching for a 144Hz monitor when I came across this Asus VZ239Q <strike>5.6 GHz</strike> **5.674 kHz** monitor.

After lots of research I couldn't find anything about such high refresh rates.

So these are my questions:

- Are there negatives about such a high refresh rate?
- Why are they not in any review?
- Are they for gaming?

Comment: Probably a typo

Comment: http://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/205d95b says 48 - 76 Hz

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a link to the place you saw this spec.

Comment: I saw them here: https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/749201/asus-vz239q-wit-zwart/specificaties/ Note: scroll down a bit to the column saying 'Refresh Rate'

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTY9uDD0x14 This may be a helpful video for you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### I came across this Asus VZ239Q 5.6 GHz Monitor.

Quote from your original question:

> I was searching for a 144Hz monitor when I came across this Asus VZ239Q 5.6 GHz monitor.

The [link](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/749201/asus-vz239q-wit-zwart/specificaties/) (from your comment) actually says:

> "Refresh rate 5,674kHz
>
> De refresh rate is het aantal keer per seconde dat het beeld wordt ververst en wordt uitgedrukt in hertz (Hz).
>           5,674kHz"

The website is a Dutch website and the Netherlands uses `,` as a decimal point. See [Decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)

So in other words the refresh rate is 5.674 kHz **not** 5.6 GHz.

Notes:

- 1GHz = 1000000kHz , so even if the value was 5674 kHz that would be 5.674 MHz not GHz.

---

Quote from your revised question:

> I was searching for a 144Hz monitor when I came across this Asus VZ239Q **5.674 kHz** monitor

That number is still wrong.

The [manufacturers specification](https://www.asus.com/Monitors/VZ239Q/specifications/) says the refresh rate is:

> Analog Signal Frequency : 54~85.5 KHz(H)/ 48~76Hz(V)
>
> Digital Signal Frequency : 54~85.5 KHz(H)/ 48~76Hz(V)

So your [link](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/749201/asus-vz239q-wit-zwart/specificaties/), which says `5,674kHz`, is wrong (by a factor of 10).

You should always check the manufacturer's website as they are most likely to have the correct data.

Of course even manufacturers can make mistakes, so it is good if you have an idea of what kind of magnitude the correct figure should be.

Comment: That still seems much too high

Comment: I converted the number from the Dutch system to the English system, but as I am pretty all-over-the-place I put GHz instead of kHz. I'm sorry! I also took the last few numbers away.

Comment: @Thijs365 See the revised answer. 
Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: tldr. The specifications you are reading are garbage. ;p

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I'll have to save up some more for a **real** 144Hz monitor.

Comment: 5.6kHz sounds much more likely to be the horizontal (line) refresh rate than the vertical rate.

Comment: @Mokubai: 5.6KHz would be awfully low for a horizontal scan rate; I don't think any broadcast system has *ever* used anything that low.  While 5600 frames/sec would be absurdly high for a stationary display that is intended to be directly viewed by people, it could be useful when viewed through moving optics or included within a scene that will be shot via high-speed camera (using the display in-shot as an alternative to compositing it in later).

Comment: @supercat you would appear to be right and I'm out by (likely) a factor of 10 as the horizontal rate is 54 to 80kHz (source: http://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/205d95b).  It's the closest figure I could guess at without a good internet connection as I was on my mobile at the time.